# Can't change color property, although the selector is working

Tags: css, joomla, joomla3.5

I've the following problem, I'm trying to change the color of the text of a "< li>" element, in joomla menu. I give the menu a link to css selector called blueMenu, this is my CSS regarding the class:

```
.blueColor {
   color: blue;
}
```

However this doesn't change the color of the text, on the other hand if I change "color" with "background-color" the background of the text becoms blue. Any idea what may causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really much depends on your template.

As already said, reasons can be inline-styles, or may more "distinct" declarations.

If you just specify the class like you did in `.blueColor` this will be treated with a lower priority as e.g. `li.blueColor` or to get even more clear both with be treated with a lower priority as e.h. `#someId.andClass .subElementClass li.blueColor a.thisIsWhatIsReallyBlue`

This is more about CSS specifications than a Joomla-Problem though.

You might check the style that is *really* applied by just launching your Development-Tools of your webbrowser (for Chrome simply press F12 or right-click on the element and inspect the element directly)
The CSS-Section on the right side might tell you about what really makes the item become blue ;)

Oh, and just a note:
As already mentioned you can use `!important` to "force" the styles to be applied, but if this is not absolutely necessary, i'd suggest to find the way to override this style on a clean way, since `!important`, if used to often, might result in a complete mess of your stylesheet.

regards

Comment: I used the firefox inspectore to verify that the style is being applied, and it seems that it is. Also as I've said when I change the color property to background-color it's working. Just as additional note, the problem is presented in other browsers also

Comment: I've found a solution, just change the way I'm selecting the element, and it's working. Your answer inspired me to do so.

Answer (score 3):

You dont give much information, but it might be that the li has a child element inside that its overwriting the li styling, make sure you using the style on the last child.

You can also force it with !important;

```
.blueColor {
   color: blue!important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with joomla but it may be inserting an inline style to whatever element you're trying to style. Right click on the element and use *inspect element* (firefox) or just *inspect* (chrome) to see if any styles were applied.

It'll look like `<div class="" style="color: blue;">`